# Loop through table and remove rows without using object index

Tags: python, loops

I've been teaching myself python, and currently I'm trying to loop through an astropy table and replace any rows that have a certain value in the second column. I can write a script that accomplishes this, but not without using a dummy index to keep track of what row I'm on.

```
for value in my_list:
    k=0
    for row in data_table: 
        if value == row[1]: 
            data_table.remove_row(k)
            data_table.add_row([replacement_row])
            k+=1
        else:
            k+=1
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not there is there a row.index() attribute or something similar that would allow me to write

```
for value in my_list:
    for row in data_table: 
        if value == row[1]: 
            data_table.remove_row(row.index())
            data_table.add_row([replacement_row])
```

The original code I have written doesn't seem like the most pythonic way.

Comment: What type is `row`? Lists have an `index` method you might be able to leverage. By the way, removing from something you're iterating over (changing the shape while you're iterating) is usually a Bad Idea.

Comment: When I run `print(type(row))` in the for loop it prints `<class 'astropy.table.row.Row'>`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed out to me that this can be done using `enumerate()`

```
for value in my_list:
    for row in enumerate(data_table): 
        if value == row[1][1]: 
            data_table.remove_row(row[0])
            data_table.add_row([replacement_row])
```